# Combine and flatten elements of array

Tags: javascript

With the below JSON content that is actually coming from an API but I'm using a json file for testing. I would like to combine the primary key and flatten the ItemList.

```
[{
        "PrimaryKey": "123",
        "ItemList": [
            {
                "SecondaryKey": "ABC",
                "Name": "Item1",
                "Description": "Sample item"
            },
            {
                "SecondaryKey": "DEF",
                "Name": "Item2",
                "Description": "Another sample item"
            }
        ],
        "IgnoreThis": [
            {
                "SomeData": "Some Data"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

The output I would like is:

```
    [{
        "PrimaryKey": 123,
        "SecondaryKey": "ABC",
        "Name": "Item1",
        "Description": "Sample Item"
    },
    {
        "PrimaryKey": 123,
        "SecondaryKey": "DEF",
        "Name": "Item2",
        "Description": "Another sample item"
    }]
```

I've got the Item list being flattened by:

```
let items = [];
items.push(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./items.json')));
let result = items.reduce((r, obj) => r.concat(obj.ItemList), []);
```

I've tried to use items.map to get the desired output nothing has worked, I don't think I understand how to chain .map and .reduce effectively as I get undefined as the result.

Any ideas how I can achieve this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by running `map` twice: get the `PrimaryKey` from the first map, then add it to all the objects inside the second map, then you flatten the array you got from the previous stage.

```js
const data = [
    {
        PrimaryKey: "123",
        ItemList: [
            {
                SecondaryKey: "ABC",
                Name: "Item1",
                Description: "Sample item",
            },
            {
                SecondaryKey: "DEF",
                Name: "Item2",
                Description: "Another sample item",
            },
        ],
        IgnoreThis: [
            {
                SomeData: "Some Data",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        PrimaryKey: "456",
        ItemList: [
            {
                SecondaryKey: "ABC",
                Name: "Item1",
                Description: "Sample item",
            },
            {
                SecondaryKey: "DEF",
                Name: "Item2",
                Description: "Another sample item",
            },
        ],
        IgnoreThis: [
            {
                SomeData: "Some Data",
            },
        ],
    },
];
    
    
const result = data.map(({ PrimaryKey, ItemList }) => ItemList.map(item => ({
    PrimaryKey,
    ...item,
}))).flat();

console.log(result);
```